# The column named cannot be found. Parameter name: columnName'

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I first added a column to the datagridview, and then I want to add a row, but it says no such columnName was found, but it exists.
I can't find how to do this, can you help me?

Datagridviewe önce column ekledim sonrada satır eklemek istiyorum ama böyle bir columnName bulunumadı diyor ama var

this is the column i added;

```
public void dilkodlariaktar()
        {

            baglanti.Open();
            SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("Select *from tablekolon where frame=@frame ", baglanti);
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@frame", "order_enter");
            SqlDataReader oku = komut.ExecuteReader();
            while (oku.Read())
            {

                DataGridViewColumn kolon = new DataGridViewColumn();
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(oku["sirano"]);
                string baslik = oku["kolonad"].ToString();
                string name = oku["kolonname"].ToString();
                kolon.HeaderText = baslik;
                kolon.Name = baslik;
                kolon.DataPropertyName = baslik;
                kolon.DisplayIndex = index;
                detaydatagridview.Columns.Add(kolon);
                
                
            }
            baglanti.Close();
        }

this is the line I want to add but it gives an error;
 public void modeldetaygetirmerenk()
        {
            baglanti.Open();

            SqlCommand komuts = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT renkRow FROM barkodModelKarti where modelNo=@modelNo", baglanti);
            komuts.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modelNo", model);
            SqlDataReader okus = komuts.ExecuteReader();
            while (okus.Read())
            {
                DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow = new DataGridViewRow();
                string deneme = detaydatagridview.Columns["Renk"].Name;

                string renksatir = okus["renkRow"].ToString();
                dataGridViewRow.Cells[deneme].Value = renksatir;
                detaydatagridview.Rows.Add(dataGridViewRow);
                

            }
            
            detaydatagridview.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
            baglanti.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem looks simple. you are selecting column `renkRow`  in the query but accessing the column `Renk` which is not present in the resultset.

so you need to correct it and safe way is to first check whether the column exists or not and then access it. you will not get an exception.

you can use the `detaydatagridview.Columns.Contains("YourColumnName")` to check whether column exists or not.

A few other suggestions, please avoid using the `AddWithValue`, you can use Parameters.Add method. also use the parameterized query to avoid SQL injection. you can also avoid `select *`, you should use only the required columns in the select.

Comment: 0



int index = detaydatagridview.Columns.IndexOf("Renk") when I do this I get an error like this. Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn'

Comment: check my answer now, you can use `Contains` method also